# MongoDB C# Driver: Updating in a less verbose way?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm currently using MongoDB and the C# driver to interact with it. Querying and inserting is very easy, but updating appears verbose and unintuitive to me. Here's an example I just wrote:

```
        var filter = new FilterDefinitionBuilder<Team>()
            .Where(t => t.Id == existingTeam.Id);
        var update = new UpdateDefinitionBuilder<Team>()
            .Set(t => t.DisbandedTime, DateTime.Now);
        _Repository.Teams.UpdateOne(filter, update);
```

I feel like I'm probably missing something, since most ORMs would achieve this in one or two lines.

I think I can write some helpers to achieve this more concisely, but are there any existing helpers for this? I'll accept an example built into the driver, or a third party library.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up making my own set of helper methods which allow me to simplify the posted code to:

```
        _Repository.Teams.Update(existingTeam)
            .Set(t => t.DisbandedTime, DateTime.Now)
            .Execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

exactly the reason why i wrote [MongoDB.Entities](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB.Entities) with which you can just do the following:

```cs
using MongoDB.Entities;
using System;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Team : Entity
    {
        public DateTime DisbandedTime { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("test", "localhost");

            DB.Update<Team>()
              .Match(t => t.ID == "xxxxxxxxxxx")
              .Modify(t => t.DisbandedTime, DateTime.Now)
              .Execute();

            //builder method alternative
            DB.Update<Team>()
              .Match(t => t.ID == "xxxxxxxxxxx")
              .Modify(b => b.CurrentDate(t => t.DisbandedTime))
              .Execute();
        }
    }
}
```